# Pattern for implementing async http handlers in F#?

Tags: asp.net, f#

Could someone tell me a good pattern to use when coding asynchronous http handlers in F#?

I have to implement `IHttpAsyncHandler` and that interface requires a `BeginProcessRequest` and `EndProcessRequest`.

Do I return `Async.StartTask`? How do I handle `state:obj` and `AsyncCallback`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head: implement handler using async workflow and then expose it with Async.AsBeginEnd

```
open System
open System.Web

type HttpAsyncHandler() = 

    let processRequestAsync (context : HttpContext) = async {
        // TODO: implement
        return()
        }

    let beginAction, endAction, _ = Async.AsBeginEnd(processRequestAsync)

    interface IHttpAsyncHandler with
        member this.BeginProcessRequest(context, callback, extraData) = beginAction(context, callback, extraData)
        member this.EndProcessRequest(iar) = endAction (iar)
        // other members omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do, exactly? If you are able, you might want to consider the [`HttpMessageHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its ilk from [`System.Net.Http`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You only have to override the

```
protected abstract Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

method, which is easy with an `async { ... } |> Async.StartAsTask`. You also get better access to the various attributes of HTTP through static typing. Various subclasses allow you to run either through ASP.NET, WCF (self-host), or even third-part platforms like [OWIN](http://whereslou.com/2012/02/20/gate-adds-owin-support-for-the-new-asp-net-web-api-beta).

Comment: I'm trying to take a JSON request, that contains a lot of statistics, parse it and append it to a blob in Azure.

Comment: Basically the only way I know of right now is to create a new empty ASP.Net web site in Azure - otherwise perhaps I could use a worker role? But how do I set that up with HttpMessageHandler?

Comment: You should be able to find more information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uscloud/archive/2012/03/22/windows-azure-for-the-asp-net-developer-series.aspx. `HttpMessageHandler` is just the most core member, but you can use other options.